# SED command to replace strings with in file

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed to replace strings with special characters in a text file. The sed command is becoming too much complicated. If someone could please help me with the exact command.

```
Code - 
sed -i 's;PS1='${HOSTNAME} [$ORACLE_SID] $PWD> ';PS1="${COL_YELLOW}'CUSTOMER TEST:${HOSTNAME}:[$ORACLE_SID]:$PWD> '${COL_END}";g'
```

I tried to escape the special characters as below but its not working.

```
sed -i 's;PS1=\'\${HOSTNAME} [\$ORACLE_SID] \$PWD> \';PS1="\${COL_YELLOW}\'CUSTOMER TEST:\${HOSTNAME}:[\$ORACLE_SID]:\$PWD> \'\${COL_END}";g' .bash_profile_backup
```

Comment: what exactly you need? Why do you think above is not working?

Comment: I want to replace the occurrence of  PS1=\'\${HOSTNAME} [\$ORACLE_SID] \$PWD> \' to PS1="\${COL_YELLOW}\'CUSTOMER TEST:\${HOSTNAME}:[\$ORACLE_SID]:\$PWD> \'\${COL_END}" using sed command but special characters are throwring issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's|PS1='\''${HOSTNAME} \[$ORACLE_SID\] $PWD> '\''|PS1="${COL_YELLOW}'\''CUSTOMER TEST:${HOSTNAME}:[$ORACLE_SID]:$PWD> '\''${COL_END}"|g' file
```

N.B. `'` need to be quoted  in both the pattern and replacement whereas `[]` needs to be escaped in the pattern only.